# Multithread parameters passing

Tags: python, multithreading, parameters

I have a class thread like this:

```
import threading, time
class th(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "Hi"
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Bye"
```

And now let's say I want every time of "sleeping" different, so I tried:

```
import treading, time
class th(threading.Thread, n):
    def run(self):
        print "Hi"
        time.sleep(n)
        print "Bye"
```

It doesn't work, and it give me a message:

> group argument must be None for now

So, how do I pass a parameter in the run?

NOTE: I did it with another function in the class like that:

```
import treading, time
class th(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "Hi"
        time.sleep(self.n)
        print "Bye"
    def get_param(self, n):
        self.n = n

var = th()
var.get_param(10)
var.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - you want to add the timeout value to the object, so you need the object to have that variable as part of it. You can do that by adding an `__init__` function that gets executed when you create the class.

```
import threading, time
class th(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def run(self):
        print "Hi"
        time.sleep(self.n)
        print "Bye"
```

See more details [here](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/iterators.html#init-method).

Comment: `selfn` should be `self.n`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about it, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Th(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(Th, self).__init__()
        self.n = n
    def run(self):
        print 'Hi'
        time.sleep(self.n)

Th(4).run()
```

Define a constructor, and pass the parameter to the constructor. The parentheses on the `class` line delimit the list of parent classes; `n` is a parameter, not a parent.